# NGXS Error: Can't resolve all parameters for TranslationEditorState: (?)

Tags: angular, typescript, ngxs, angular9

I'm using NGXS for state management in Angular 9 application. In one of the state classes, any dependency injection causes an error "Error: Can't resolve all parameters for TranslationEditorState: (?)."  I've tried injecting a service and even the HttpClient, but the issue remains the same. In fact, for any of the state classes I get the same error. Could it have something to do with the sequence of Module injection in app.module?

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { NgxsModule } from '@ngxs/store';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { AuthInterceptor } from './auth/auth.interceptor';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { configFactory } from './shared/utils/config.factory';
import { NgxsFormPluginModule } from '@ngxs/form-plugin';
import { NgxsLoggerPluginModule } from '@ngxs/logger-plugin';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ConfigService } from './shared/services/config/config.service';
import { NgxsReduxDevtoolsPluginModule } from '@ngxs/devtools-plugin';
import { TranslationEditorState } from './shared/state/translation-editor.state';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { TranslationEditorModule } from './translation-editor/translation-editor.module';
import { ApplicationSectorState, ConfigState, InitialDataState, MenuState } from './shared/state';

const states = [ApplicationSectorState, ConfigState, InitialDataState, MenuState, TranslationEditorState];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    AuthModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NgxsModule.forRoot(states),
    NgxsFormPluginModule.forRoot(),
    NgxsReduxDevtoolsPluginModule.forRoot(),
    NgxsLoggerPluginModule.forRoot(),
    SharedModule,
    TranslationEditorModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    ConfigService,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: configFactory,
      multi: true,
      deps: [ConfigService],
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**State Class**

```
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { GetTranslations } from '../actions';
import { TranslationEditor } from '../model';
import { Action, State, StateContext } from '@ngxs/store';
import { TranslationEditorService } from '../../translation-editor/service/translation-editor.service';

@State<TranslationEditor>({
  name: 'translationEditor',
  defaults: {
    translations: {},
  },
})
export class TranslationEditorState {
  constructor(private translationEditorService: TranslationEditorService) {}

  @Action(GetTranslations)
  getTranslations({ getState, patchState }: StateContext<TranslationEditor>, { application, environment, languageCodes }) {
    return this.translationEditorService
      .getTranslations(application, environment, languageCodes)
      .pipe(
        tap(translations => {
          patchState({
            ...getState(),
            translations,
          });
        })
      )
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
      });
  }
}
```

**Service:**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Store } from '@ngxs/store';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { InitialData, LabelValue } from '../../shared/model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TranslationEditorService {
  baseUrl: string;

  constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient, private readonly store: Store) {
    this.baseUrl = this.store.selectSnapshot<string>(state => state.appConfig.baseApiUrl);
  }

  getInitialData(): Observable<InitialData> {
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}/initial-data`;
    return this.http.get<InitialData>(url)
  }

  getTranslations(application: LabelValue, environment: LabelValue, languageCodes: Array<string>): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}/applications/translations${application.value}/env/${environment.value}/translations`;
    return this.http.post(url, languageCodes);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will need to add @Injectable for IVY.

https://github.com/ngxs/store/blob/master/docs/advanced/ivy-migration-guide.md